# Flutter Build APK: Failed -Could not initialize class 'org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache'

Tags: flutter

When install connectivity package , can not build apk in the connectivity version 2.0.1 .

Comment: What is your gradle version?

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'

Comment: What about your Java sdk/jdk? If it is not up to date, you can upgrade it from here: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html

Comment: And you can try to run this simple example to understand the reason for the problem:
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/connectivity/connectivity/example

Comment: java jdk version  is 14.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
android->gradle->wrapper->gradle-wrapper.properties
```

file and open it.
change this line of code

```
"distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip"
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip
```

and then;
type this command below terminal and enter

```
flutter clean
```

when its finished; run

```
flutter run
```

after these steps, if you still get errors; follow these instructions at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68612798/15728644).