# Unable to find bundled Java version with flutter doctor, after updating Android studio Arctic Fox(2020.3.1) on M1 Apple Silicon

Tags: android, flutter, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I'm facing a weird issue. Before I updated my Android Studio, everything went fine in flutter doctor. Once I've updated Android Studio, when I run the doctor, it's showing "Unable to find bundled Java version". I've already downloaded Java installer and installed it on my M1 Mac, but after I restarted, running flutter doctor still shows the same error. The weird thing is, when I uninstall the Arctic Fox version and re-install the older Android Studio version, everything goes fine again when running the doctor. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Which `$JAVA_HOME` directory is used? You might wanna check your Java version is compatible with stable AS 2020.3.1 and M1 as well

Comment: here is the answer for this problem when you still wanna using Android Studio Arctic Fox version https://stackoverflow.com/a/68575967/9101876

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to find bundled Java version on Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281702/unable-to-find-bundled-java-version-on-flutter)

Answer (score 193, accepted):

The answer is already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68575967/15728644).

For Mac User:

Set `Java_Home` path using below article & then after applying this [command](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/#what-is-usrlibexecjava-home).

after that type below command in terminal:

```
cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre

ln -s ../jre jdk

ln -s "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" jdk

flutter doctor -v
```

Comment: it seems now flutter requires java 11 rather than java 8 since new android studio artic fox update

Comment: I just went through the process with the latest flutter and the latest android studio. The solution presented here eliminates the "unable to find java version" error but then you get a ClassNotFoundException on some XML parser classes when trying to accept licenses. That's because Android Studio now comes with Java 1 which does not have a lot of the JEE stuff anymore.

The simple solution to all this is to set your JAVA_HOME env variable to any Java 8 install you may have around, and this fixes everything.

Comment: Working on Mac OS

Comment: works for me without harming pre installed java version 11.0

Comment: This worked for me - note I had to manually install the latest JDK first (I am using MacOS big sur) apparently it does not come installer. After that this worked perfectly.

Comment: Worked for me with Big Sur. But would be nice to explain what this `ln -s` command is doing?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/118502

Answer (score 89):

If you are using Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1.

On Mac

1. Open "Applications" in Finder. Then right click on Android Studio, select "Show Package Contents".
2. Inside it, open the "Contents" folder. Inside it you will see folder with named "jbr".
3. Simply duplicate the "jbr" folder. Then, rename the copy folder to "jre".
4. Then, flutter doctor. The "Unable to find bundled Java version" warning will disappear.

Thanks to @Javi for provided with alternative method.
For Step 2 & 3, `ln -s jbr jre` also can get the job done. And I think this is the best method to do.

Comment: You my friend are a genius, I can confirm this was the fix for me as well on Windows 11 using Android studio 2022.1.1 thank you very much sir!

Comment: Hey, how did you come up with this solution? Anyway, it worked for me too.

Comment: This is the only working solution for me.

Comment: wow! after 2 hours trying, this helps me! thanks

Comment: Even though this fixes the problem, I'd rather create a symbolic link instead of copying the folder. This way, if something changes in the `jbr` folder, you don't need to copy the folder again. 


In the step 2, just type `ln -s jbr jre`. This will fix the problem.

Comment: re: soft link solution. Terminal app on Mac OS doesn't have full disk access by default which means you won't be able to create a soft link, even with a sudo. Full Disk access can be granted under System Settings under Privacy & Security.

Comment: Cannot believe this worked. This is insanely dumb

Answer (score 52):

Here is a little fuller answer for everything I had to do to get Android Studio set up on my M1.

1. Install Android Studio to the Applications folder
2. Create a symbolic link to from the `jre` folder to a new `jdk` folder. (Due to [this bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/76215#issuecomment-864407892))

```sh
cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre
ln -s ../jre jdk
```

3. Set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable

```sh
nano ~/.zshrc
```

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home"
```

```sh
source ~/.zshrc
```

4. [Install Android SDK Command-line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61993738/flutter-doctor-android-licenses-gives-a-java-error) (needed for accepting license)
5. At this point it should work now (assuming you've also added flutter to your path)

```sh
flutter doctor
```

Comment: The `command-line tools` is important for accepting the packages

Comment: I faced similar issue on non M1 mac. The above solution fixed. Seems like its not related to M1 chip. This simple hack solved the issue with "file bundle with java not found".

Comment: There is no `jdk' directory inside `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/` on my machine though. I'm also on a M1 Mac. Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: @Isuru, Right, that's the problem. Writing `ln -s` creates the `jdk` directory as a soft linking pointing to the existing `jre` directory.

Comment: This works for me

Answer (score 27):

This is the Windows fix, and it appears to work for me. I am using Android Studio2022.1.1.19

1. First, right-click the Android Studio icon and open the file directory(location). Your installation folder should be at "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio".
2. When you are already at the Android Studio installation root folder, you will see two folders: "**jbr**" and "**jre**".
3. Copy all the files inside the "**jbr**" folder to the "**jre**" folder, then try it again.

**Note: This fix is working on my end; just comment down below if it didn`t work on your end.**

Comment: worked for me, but why?!

Comment: @Sheldeeb, then, thats good!

Comment: This did not work for me

Comment: Worked for me been facing this for 3 days

Comment: Worked too. Android Studio 2022.2 and trying to run a Flutter 2.10 project (3.13 is the last version at the time of this comment).

Comment: be careful if you have multiple versions of Android studio installed

Answer (score 14):

In my case, on a macOS Ventura with Intel processor, I had to follow the steps below in order to make Flutter work after upgrading Android Studio to Electric Eel:

1. `cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/`
2. `ln -s jbr jre`
3. `flutter config --android-studio-dir /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents`

Step 3 was important, without it `flutter doctor --android-licenses` would always fail...

Comment: Maybe not fully related here, as question title states M1 processor, but I still think it might be helpful to some.

Comment: this solution worked for me on my M2 Mac Mini

Answer (score 6):

I did install a fresh version of JAVA SDK, flutter, Android Studio and run the below command directly on the terminal one by one to fix 'Unable to find bundled Java version. ' issue.

1. cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre
2. ln -s ../jre jdk
3. ln -s "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" jdk
4. flutter doctor -v

Now, you should be able to see the error is disappeared in flutter doctor description in terminal.

Answer (score 6):

Works on macOS
This will link `jbr` folder to `jre`

```
cd /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents

or

cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents

ln -s jbr jre
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: this steps are working for me

Comment: In case you face "ln: jre: Operation not permitted", simply allow Full disk access to iTerm. See https://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/

Answer (score 4):

Run Flutter doctor, if there´s an error indicating that the java bundled can´t be found (specially if you have Android Studio version Artic Fox), run this commands if using Mac:

1. cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre
2. ln -s ../jre jdk
3. ln -s "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" jdk
4. Flutter Doctor

Answer (score 4):

This solution is for M1 Mac User

1. Find your local Java version by typing `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`. If didn't exist, install the latest ARM Java version [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk17-mac)
2. Set Java_Home path (in my case jdk-17.0.1.jdk) by typing `/usr/libexec/java_home /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home`
3. Type all of these in terminal

> ```
> cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre
> ln -s ../jre jdk
> ln -s "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" jdk
> ```

4. Finally run `flutter doctor -v` to see all the details changes

Comment: I typed `zsh: permission denied: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home` into Terminal, hoping to set the Java_Home path and it said `permission denied  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home`. Is there somewhere else I should type? How do I give it permission?

Comment: You can us sudo:
`sudo export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home`

or chown
`sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home`

This will give you the ownership of the directory, so you don't have to use sudo everytime you want to access it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error after updating Android Studio to 2020.3.1 Patch 3 (on MAC).

After upgrading Flutter from 2.2.2 to 2.5.3 problem was solved.

I also installed "Android SDK Command-line Tools". It's installation is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68492909/6839552

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution worked with a slight modification for me. I had to add the ***-f*** (or use --force) option to make it work (this is because ln failed with file exists and I kept ignoring that - the existing file must have had a problem).

```
cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre
ln -s -f ../jre jdk
ln -s -f "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" jdk

flutter doctor -v
```

I'm running macOS Monterey

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the simplest option (MAC):

- Navigate to: `cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre`
- Create a directory: `mkdir jdk`
- Create a soft link: `ln -s Contents jdk/Contents`

Answer (score 0):

COPY folder
/Applications/Android Studio Preview.app/Contents/jre/Contents
to
/Applications/Android Studio Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents

Comment: This workaround might violates standard AS default JAVA_HOME directory, have you already tried in your local?

Comment: You can check this script code，YOUR_PATH/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/android/android_studio.dart，and find the code just like this `globals.fs.path.join(directory, 'jre', 'jdk', 'Contents', 'Home')`, then you can get what path you should set for the "doctor"

Answer (score 0):

It's @crzorz 's additional answer worked for me. "YOUR_PATH/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/android/android_studio.dart". At the bottom of the file, you'll see lines similar to "globals.fs.path.join(directory, 'jre', 'jdk', 'Contents', 'Home')" which @crzorz mentioned.

These lines clearly show on MacOS (old and new versions) and other OS how "flutter doctor" finds the so-called bundled Java.

I use Android Studio Electric Eel. What I did to fix the issue was "create a symbolic link named jre pointing to jbr". Because folder jbr (JetBean Runtime) has the java.exe and other Java Runtime files, but flutter doctor still tries to find a folder named jre.

Comment: This is not an answer. You must comment such things!

Answer (score 0):

**Update to:**

**Android Estudio 2022.1 Electric eel + Java 19 + VS Code + Windows 10 x64**

***Before:*** Make sure you have **JAVA_PATH** correctly

1 - `Run` **CMD** as **Administrator** [**Not POWERSHELL**, because **`mklink`** only work for **CMD**]

2- `Run` the `mklink /d "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre" "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr"`

3- `Run` command `flutter doctor` and Problem solved, but then apears the licenses problem, so

4- `Run` command `flutter doctor --android-licenses` wait and accept all

Other way doesn't work, thrown a error: " bla bla bla...***already exist***..." why?

Because the structure of **`mklink`** command: `mklink` `[OPTIONS: /d /j /h rd del]` `"Path+Name folder/file you want {jre}"` `"Path+Name folder/file linked {jbr}"`

***Traduced to human language:*** Make a Symbolic link **[mklink /d]** "there with the name **jre**" to the folder "that is there with the name **jbr**"

Make sure to use "double quotes" for the files paths and say **"please"** and not **"Just do it"** (cmd smell your hurry).

If you dont do it like this, will have problems with `sdkmanager` and launch devices, because the new Android Estudio don't use **jre** and that's why many android devices don't launch, and have the ***60 second problem***.

Answer (score 0):

Copying all contents of JDK and pasting it into a JRE file, worked for me.

After that, I updated my ENV path.