# Java configuration problem for flutter on mac m1

Tags: android, macos, flutter, dart

I recently encountered a problem with flutter doctor showing me an error but I didn't have this problem before it says "Unable to find bundled Java version" and nothing of the changes I could make was useful .
I install on the advice of some java on my machine but the error still appears.

How to deal with this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68569430/flutter-unable-to-find-bundled-java-versionflutter-doctor-after-updated-andro?rq=1)

The problem is due to the update of android studio in its Arctic Fox version (2020.3.1) for Mac M1 (Apple Silicon).

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.