# Android Studio after update Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\lib\jvm.cfg'

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio

After updating Android Studio to Electric Eel version, I try to build an apk from a Flutter project it gives the message

```
Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\lib\jvm.cfg'
```

I noticed that `Program Files\Android` contained two Android Studio folders with the other named as `Android Studio1` and it contains the correct folders, while the other contained only this `jre` folder  and the file `jvm.cfg` doesn't exist, is there something I can do other than deleting the whole thing and re installing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68569430/unable-to-find-bundled-java-version-with-flutter-doctor-after-updating-android)
You just need to copy the contents of jbr folder to jre folder and it works